# use variable for row_num application.index

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to get two non consecutive columns into a two dimensional array so:

The source range looks like this:

```
a 1 apple
b 2 banana
c 3 pear
d 4 orange
e 5 grape
```

I want my array to look like this:

Index 1-
[a,
apple]

Index 2-
[b,
banana]

Index 3-
[c,
pear]

etc.

I am using this:

```
vArr = Application.index(Range("A:AU"), [row(2:30)], Array(1, 4))
```

This works fine except I'll always have to hard code my last row. I want this:

```
vArr = Application.index(Range("A:AU"), [row(2:<lastRow>)], Array(1, 4))
```

This does not work at all.  I am assuming I cannot use a variable to represent the run_num in the index function.  If I put a 0 in for the row_num it will only return the entire row on one column.  As soon as I put in the array for non contiguous cols it fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Someone commented for me to use:
         vArr = Application.index(Range("A:D"), Rows("2:" & lastRow), Array(1, 4))
That doesn't seem to work.  It gives me variant/variant(1 to 29, 1 to 1638)


Plus every index is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and wanted to post an answer for anyone else who was wondering:

```
Application.index(.Value2, _
            .Worksheet.Evaluate("ROW(" & .Columns(1).Address & ")-1"), _
            Array(1, 4))
```

Per comments from below:

This is a better representation of the answer I asked for in the original request:

```
vArr = Application.index(Range("A:AU"), Application.Evaluate("Row(2:" & lastRow & ")"), Array(1, 4))
```

Comment: What's the `With` block? There's no `With` block anywhere in this page, which makes this answer confusing for readers.

Comment: Also, where is `lastRow` in the above solution?

Comment: Last row not used.  Worksheet.evaluate finds the row length by looking at the specified columns.  I believe that's how it works.

Comment: `vArr = Application.index(Range("A:AU"), Application.Evaluate("Row(2:" & lastRow & ")"), Array(1, 4))` is the answer you asked for in the above question. Why don't you just amend this to your answer?